# Question about AWS Organizations' Member Using Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

If I am member of an organization on AWS, and I use my member account to upload an Elastic Beanstalk app to a specific region via CLI, will it show up for management account as well? Or do I need to change something in settings somewhere to make the app upload to organization's AWS and not my own console. Need clarification

Currently, I used my member account keys in CLI to create and deploy elastic beanstalk app in specific region. It is working fine. However, the organization management account cannot see the environment in their console.

Any clarification would be very much appreciated! As I am not expert in AWS and have only used it as IAM user before to deploy apps.

Comment: It is solved. Turns out I needed IAM account afterall. The member account created app in my own console separately.